# How to compare values in several fields for each ID in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a table that contains alert information for replacement orders.(br)(br)
I need to confirm for each alert that for each Order ID in the alert ID:
     The Buyer names are the same
     The paid date is different between each alert.

```
Alert_ID | Order_ID | Buyer_ID | Item  | Quantity | Paid_date
01       | 001A     | Adam     | Apple | 2        | 01/01/2019
01       | 001A     | Adam     | Orange| 3        | 01/01/2019
01       | 001B     | Adam     | Apple | 4        | 01/03/2019
01       | 001B     | Adam     | Orange| 3        | 01/03/2019
01       | 001C     | Adam     | Apple | 3        | 01/07/2019
01       | 001C     | Adam     | Orange| 3        | 01/07/2019
02       | 002A     | Pam      | Banana| 2        | 01/21/2019
02       | 002A     | Pam      | Grapes| 1        | 01/21/2019
02       | 002B     | Pam      | Banana| 2        | 01/30/2019
02       | 001B     | Pam      | Grapes| 4        | 01/30/2019
04       | 004A     | Dave     | Apple | 2        | 01/01/2019
04       | 004B     | Mary     | Apple | 3        | 01/01/2019
```

Initially this was a 1:1 relationship of replacement claims to original claims. 
I split the table in two by alert_id with the replacement order in one sub query and the original order In the other, then I could compare all the fields I wanted between alerts and orders.

```
select
        *
from
        (
                with repl as(
                        select
                                Alert_ID, Order_ID, Buyer_ID, Paid_date
                                ROW_NUMBER () over(partition by alert_id order by alert_id, Order_id) AS RN
                        from <MY ALERT TABLE>
                )
                SELECT * FROM repl WHERE RN = 1
        ) A
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
                with repl as(
                        select
                                Alert_ID, Order_ID, Buyer_ID, Paid_date
                                ROW_NUMBER () over(partition by alert_id order by alert_id, Order_id) AS RN
                        from <MY ALERT TABLE>
                )
                SELECT R1.* 
                FROM repl R1 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN repl R2
                ON R1.ALERT_ID = R2.ALERT_ID AND R1.RN < R2.RN
                WHERE R2.RN IS NULL
        ) B
        ON A.ALERT_ID = B.ALERT_ID
WHERE

        a.order_id=b.order_id
        and a.buyer_id <> b.buyer_id
        and a.paid_date > b.paid_date
```

This worked fine for 1:1, but with 1:n I'm loosing out on all orders that appear in between the first and last row number.

Expected Result:

Return exceptions to the rules

```
Alert_ID | Order_ID | Buyer_ID | Item  | Quantity | Paid_date
04       | 004A     | Dave     | Apple | 2        | 01/01/2019
04       | 004B     | Mary     | Apple | 3        | 01/01/2019
```

Comment: . . Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to get the exceptions -- that is, `alter_id`/`order_id` pairs with different names?

If so:

```
select Alert_ID, Order_ID
from repl
group by Alert_ID, Order_ID
having min(buyer_id) <> max(buyer_id)
```